# How to handle relative path and absolute path in Localhost

Tags: c#, .net, url, relative-path, absolute-path

OK most of us develop and test the Asp.NET Web Applications in our localhost before publishing them to the production server. But to me, localhost is a pain sometimes since I cannot get the absolute path properly. Because lets say my app is located in `http://localhost/MyApp/` I cannot properly get the host. I can get it with a couple of code but I like to make it more generic so whenever some other developer puts the same application in another location such as `http://localhost/TheirApp`, then it should work fine.

**Sample Problem:**

Whenever I use absolute path like this `/aboutus.aspx`, it causes this `http://localhost/aboutus.aspx` and omits `MyApp`. If I use relative path, then it becomes `http://localhost/MyApp/IamHere.aspx/aboutus.aspx` which is rather disturbing.

So if `Request.Url.Authority` or `Request.Url.Host` would return `http://localhost/MyApp` then we could append our url using these and find a nice solution.

**An Alternative Solution:**

I could do this:

```
if(Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("localhost"))
{
    string[] segments = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split("/");
    var localHost = Request.Url.Authority + "/" + segments[0];
}
```

then I can use `localHost` variable and append my path to it.

But I like to learn how you guys are dealing with such problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of what you are trying to achieve, but you can use the tilde (`~`) to refer to the web application's root and that should solve your problem.

```
string url = ResolveUrl("~/aboutus.apsx");
```

The ASP.NET application will figure out by itself if `~` should be `localhost`, `localhost:34534`, `someserver.net/Deep/Path` or anything else.

Comment: u don't even need the tilde. using bare filename will be current directory of current web app of current host and port. or you can say the same thing more explicitly ./whatever.aspx

Comment: Mind if I cried? How come I forgot `~/` all these days :/

Answer (score 1):

It's the job of well behaving apps to work on whichever host and whichever path, either through a config parameter or the app figures it out. It shouldn't be too difficult to figure out the path (the bits between) the program/script itself and hostname. In any case for the most part the script/program can use relative paths only, the webserver adds the other bits automatically for you...so no need to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an alternative could be to create a link or what I would call a 'pseudo path' to the targetted folder. For example you create a link 'TheirApp' that points to the folder 'MyApp' (or the reverse):

```
TheirApp --> MyApp

MyApp --> TheirApp
```

Or you could do so in appropriate subfolders:

```
My/Path/MyApp --> Their/Path/TheirApp

Their/Path/TheirApp --> My/Path/MyApp
```